# My slide navigation menu does not hide the content that it was sliding over

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried my best to make sense of the title but for more references, I am giving screenshots below the menu when it slides over the page covering the content the content should be hidden but its not

Before:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/caYOz.jpg

After:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6mW4.jpg

Here's the CSS for my navigation:

```
/* navbar Start*/

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: -100%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #F68B50;
    /*background: linear-gradient(375deg, #F68B50, #4114a1, #f92c78);*/
    /* background: linear-gradient(375deg, #1cc7d0, #2ede98); */
    /* background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #e3eefe 0%, #efddfb 100%);*/
    transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

#active:checked~.wrapper {
    /*left: 0;*/
    right: 0;
}

.menu-btn {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    right: 20px;
    /*left: 20px; */
    top: 20px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    /*color: #fff;*/
    /*background: linear-gradient(90deg, #f92c78, #4114a1);*/
    /* background: linear-gradient(375deg, #1cc7d0, #2ede98); */
    /* background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #e3eefe 0%, #efddfb 100%); */
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.menu-btn span,
.menu-btn:before,
.menu-btn:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(50% - 1px);
    left: 30%;
    width: 40%;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #000000;
    transition: transform .6s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
}

.menu-btn:before {
    transform: translateY(-8px);
}

.menu-btn:after {
    transform: translateY(8px);
}

.close {
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: background .6s;
}


/* closing animation */

#active:checked+.menu-btn span {
    transform: scaleX(0);
}

#active:checked+.menu-btn:before {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    border-color: #fff;
}

#active:checked+.menu-btn:after {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    border-color: #fff;
}

.wrapper ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 60%;
    left: 50%;
    height: 90%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    list-style: none;
    text-align: right;
}

.wrapper ul li {
    height: 10%;
    margin: 15px 0;
}

.wrapper ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding: 5px 30px;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    line-height: 50px;
    margin: 5px 30px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: transform .6s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
}

.wrapper ul li a:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    background: #fff;
    /*background: linear-gradient(#14ffe9, #ffeb3b, #ff00e0);*/
    /*background: linear-gradient(375deg, #1cc7d0, #2ede98);*/
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    border-radius: 50px;
    transform: scaleY(0);
    z-index: -1;
    transition: transform 0.3s ease;
}

.wrapper ul li a:hover:after {
    transform: scaleY(1);
}

.wrapper ul li a:hover {
    color: #4114a1;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}

.product a img {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: -400px;
    top: -200px;
}

.product a img {
    display: none;
}

.product a:hover img {
    display: inherit;
}

.content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: -1;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    color: #202020;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

.content .title {
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.content p {
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: 600;
}

#active:checked~.wrapper ul li a {
    opacity: 1;
    align-items: center;
}

.wrapper ul li a {
    transition: opacity 1.2s, transform 1.2s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
    transform: translateX(100px);
    font-family: 'LemonMilk';
    align-items: center;
}

#active:checked~.wrapper ul li a {
    transform: none;
    transition-timing-function: ease, cubic-bezier(.1, 1.3, .3, 1);
    /* easeOutBackを緩めた感じ */
    transition-delay: .6s;
    transform: translateX(-100px);
}

.pages-nav--open {
    pointer-events: auto;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.pages-nav__item {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    min-height: 300vh;
}

.pages-nav .pages-nav__item--social {
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1.2s, opacity 1.2s;
    transition: transform 1.2s, opacity 1.2s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.2, 1, 0.3, 1);
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.2, 1, 0.3, 1);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 20px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 20px, 0);
}

.pages-nav--open .pages-nav__item--social {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.35s;
    transition-delay: 0.35s;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.link {
    font-size: 0.85em;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.link:hover,
.link:focus {
    color: #fff;
}

.link--page {
    display: block;
    color: #cecece;
    text-align: center;
}

.link--page:not(.link--faded)::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 2px;
    margin: 5px 0 0 -15px;
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s;
    transition: transform 0.3s;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(0, 1, 1);
    transform: scale3d(0, 1, 1);
}

.link--page:hover:before {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
}

.link--faded {
    color: #4f4f64;
}

.link--faded:hover,
.link--faded:focus {
    color: #5c5edc;
}

.link--page.link--faded {
    font-size: 0.65em;
}

.link--social {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin: 0 0.75em;
}

.text-hidden {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    color: transparent;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 40em) {
    .js .pages-nav {
        display: block;
        padding: 10px 20px 0 20px;
        text-align: left;
    }
    .pages-nav__item {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .pages-nav__item--small {
        display: inline-block;
        width: auto;
        margin-right: 5px;
    }
    .pages-nav__item--social {
        font-size: 0.9em;
    }
    .menu-button {
        top: 15px;
        right: 10px;
        left: auto;
    }
    .info {
        font-size: 0.85em;
    }
    .poster {
        margin: 1em;
    }
}

/* ///////////////////// navbar end ///////////////////////// */
```

and here's my css for the page this is on:

```
.typewritter {
  height: 80vh;
  /*This part is important for centering*/
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.typing-demo {
  width: 28%;
  animation: typing 4s steps(22), blink .5s step-end infinite alternate;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-right: 3px solid;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 2em;
}

@keyframes typing {
  from {
    width: 0
  }
}

@keyframes blink {
  50% {
    border-color: transparent
  }
}


body {
    margin: 0px;
}

#container {
    /* Center the text in the viewport. */
    position: absolute;

  display: flex;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 80pt;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;

    /* This filter is a lot of the magic, try commenting it out to see how the morphing works! */
    filter: url(#threshold) blur(0.6px);
}

/* Your average text styling */
#text1, #text2 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;

    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size: 80pt;

    text-align: center;

    user-select: none;
}
```

If any more info is needed I'll be happy to provide it!

Comment: please make a codepen of your code for more clarification

Comment: https://codepen.io/majorrip/pen/jOmVYoL

Comment: as you can see that when the menu appears the change of text still remains now cow can i make it disappear or make the menu so that the menu is its own thing

Comment: i have a nice idea to make the text below the menu

Comment: just set a greater z-index to .wrapper also u need to give a z-index to .menu-btn else it would be below the wrapper

Comment: doing this worked in the codepen for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all you need to do is just set a greater z-index to .wrapper also u need to give a z-index to .menu-btn else it would be below the wrapper
this should be your code

```css
.menu-btn{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 12;
  right: 20px;
  /*left: 20px; */
  top: 20px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  /*color: #fff;*/
  /*background: linear-gradient(90deg, #f92c78, #4114a1);*/
  /* background: linear-gradient(375deg, #1cc7d0, #2ede98); */
 /* background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #e3eefe 0%, #efddfb 100%); */
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.wrapper{
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
  right: -100%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #F68B50;
  /*background: linear-gradient(375deg, #F68B50, #4114a1, #f92c78);*/
  /* background: linear-gradient(375deg, #1cc7d0, #2ede98); */
 /* background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #e3eefe 0%, #efddfb 100%);*/
  transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
}
```